# 404 not found or forbidden on localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, wildfly

'I have problem in accessing my app from the `localhost`. I added the project in `WildFly` server version 17 via Eclipse.

I get ***404 not found*** when I open `localhost:8080/vaadin-app/ui`.
I get ***forbidden*** when  I open `localhost:8080/vaadin-app`. Where am I doing wrong?

Could it be that the problem is related to the `web.xml` file? Because I realized that, `web.xml` was not existing. Therefore I created it `web.xml` manually.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.kamil.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8.0</java.version>
  </properties>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>  

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Main.java:

```
@SpringUI(path = "/ui")
@Title("First Vaadin Web Application Page")
public class MainView extends UI{

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        verticalLayout.addComponent(new com.vaadin.ui.Label("Welcome to Vaadin!!!"));
        setContent(verticalLayout);
    }
}
```

App.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<display-name>vaadin-app</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>ui</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: web.xml is not required with Spring Boot. Check your logs for the context with which application is deployed. Possibly it is "" with newer version of Spring Boot. you can with localhost:8080/ui removing you web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Extend your App.java from:

```
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

And add here this method:

```
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(App.class);
    }
```

In last, i recommend you to set war name. You can do it with adding this to your **pom.xml**:

```
<finalName>vaadin-app</finalName>
```